# Spark dataframe negate filter conditions

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying apply a negation of filter condition on the DataFrame as shown below.

```
!(`Ship Mode` LIKE '%Truck%')
```

Which is throwing an exception below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.3] failure: identifier expected

(!(`Ship Mode` LIKE '%Truck%'))
  ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser.parseExpression(SqlParser.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.filter(DataFrame.scala:748)
    at Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Where as the same kind of negative filter conditions are working fine in MySQL. Please find below

```
mysql> select count(*) from audit_log where !(operation like '%Log%' or operation like '%Proj%');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      129 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Can anyone please let me know if this is planned to be fixed in Spark DataFrames in future releases or should I raise a JIRA.

Comment: Have you tried using 'NOT LIKE' ?

Comment: Yes, But I do not want to use not like as the expression may get quite complex and I just want to negate them as a whole.

Comment: Ok. Have you also considered using `rdd`  + `filterNot`  so that you can `registerTable` and skip the `! like` in your query?

Comment: @ccheneson There is no need for that. `NOT` clause can negate group of predicates, `HiveContext` supports `!` and DataFrame API provides `not` function and unary `!` operator (I am not sure if the last one works in Java though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using plain `SQLContext` where `!` is not supported:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val data = Seq(("a", 1, 3), ("b", 2, 6), ("c", -1, 2))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data).toDF("x1", "x2", "x3") 
df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE ! (x2 >  2 OR x3 < 4)").show

// java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.25] failure: identifier expected
//
// SELECT * FROM df WHERE ! (x2 >  2 OR x3 < 4)
//                         ^
```

It can be easily replaced with `NOT`:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE NOT (x2 >  2 OR x3 < 4)").show

// +---+---+---+
// | x1| x2| x3|
// +---+---+---+
// |  b|  2|  6|
// +---+---+---+
```

If you still want to use `!` you should work with `HiveContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val df1 = hiveContext.createDataFrame(data).toDF("x1", "x2", "x3")
df1.registerTempTable("df")

hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE ! (x2 >  2 OR x3 < 4)").show

// +---+---+---+
// | x1| x2| x3|
// +---+---+---+
// |  b|  2|  6|
// +---+---+---+
```